# symfony 2.1 : insert image with PHP script and Twig

Tags: twig, symfony-2.1

With simple PHP we can insert an image generated by a PHP script, like :

```
<img src="image_script.php">
```

How can we do this with Symfony and Twig ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to link to a .php file you already have? Do you want to link to a Symfony2 action that outputs an image?

Comment: One or the other will be good. I can write a php file or an action that creates images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in Symfony2 and twig almost like in plain php:

```
<img src="{{ path("img_action") }}" alt="" />
```

where `img_action` is the route name for the action that returns an image.

In that action, create a new `Response` instance, set its contents to the image, set the content-type header to the appropriate MIME type, then `return` it.

Comment: Great, this is just what I needed. Just because I'm curious, how do we handle the case of a php file that create an image ?

Comment: You put the php file's location in the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at LiipImagineBundle :

https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle

This bundle allows you to create a cache of resized images.